# curl up navigation on view based application in ios apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

i have faced some problem while navigating from one class to another with the curl-up animation style

i have did 2 test projects one with View based application & another navigation based application & also created 2 classes in each and a button on the first screen

following is my event handler for that button

```
-(IBAction)OnclickButton
{
SecondViewController * viewController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                }
                completion:NULL];

}
```

my problem is

project with navigation based template is working fine its navigating to second page with curl up animation ,,

but

in the project with navigation based template ,its not navigating to the second page on click of the button instead it will give curl up effect n reload the same page
 why its happening so,, i am planing to apply this curl up animation to my existing project which is created in view based template

can any one tell where i gone wrong,,, how can i navigate with curl up animation(but not using the partial animation API)

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B'coz you set self.view

```
transitionWithView:self.view.window
```

you need to change view which you call..

Comment: @ jagdish  ya it should navigate from current view know thats y,,, n also its working fine with navigation based template know

Comment: you need CAAnimation on view call.. Use QuartzCore framework.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=QuartzCore